# What happens if a Muggle born wizard/witch can't afford Hogwarts supplies?

Tags: harry-potter

What happens if a Muggle-born wizard/witch receives a Hogwarts acceptance letter but their family is very poor and doesn't have money to buy the school things on the shopping list? Would Hogwarts give them some kind of financial help?

Comment: Makes me wonder where someone from an orphanage (naming no names that must not be named) would get supplies

Comment: if it's a fan game: a bunch of sidequests, that double as a tutorial

Comment: A good question, but alas a topic already covered (in significantly more detail) in a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do know from one of Dumbledore's memories that Tom Riddle could go to Hogwarts with a fund from the school, which is presumably available to students in financial hardship.

> When [Tom] had finished he turned to Dumbledore and said baldly, "I haven't got any money."
> "That is easily remedied," said Dumbledore, drawing a leather money pouch from his pocket. "There is a fund at Hogwarts for those who require assistance to buy books and robes. You might have to buy some of your spellbooks and so on secondhand, but —"
>  <sub>- *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, Chapter 13: The Riddle Secret</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In "Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince", you see in Dumbledore's memory that he gave Tom Riddle a sack of gold, in order to buy school supplies.